# formality issues regarding the 「調子はどうだい？」 greeting

Tags: set-phrases, keigo

(1) ”元気なの?” and "調子はどうだい？" are pretty much equivalent in *meaning* and *formality*, right? The ”元気なの?” being a little feminine because of the "なの"? And, "調子はどうだい？" is rarely / never used by native speakers? I don't think I've ever heard it used.

(2) "調子はどうだい？" is just an informal way to say "調子はどうですか？", right?

(3) Can I up the formality of 「調子はどうですか？」? Perhaps:
"ご調子は、どうですか？"
"ご調子は、いかがですか？" // <--- best?
"ご調子は、おいかがですか？"
"ご調子は、どうなさっていますか？"

(4) When I am greeting someone in a business setting, can I pop-off a:
"ご調子は、いかがですか？"
and not have the native speaker think that I sound weird? Rather, I'd want him/her to think I sound *different*, but not *weird*.

thanks.

Comment: 「調子はどうだい」 sounds like an 親父 greeting to me.

Comment: 「調子」や「いかが」に、「お/ご」はつけません。

Comment: Directly translating 'how are you' in to Japanese doesn't make cultural sense since that isn't how people greet business associates here. Any way you say it may be grammatically correct, but sound culturally weird. What is said depends on whether it's a first time meeting or not, what the levels of all people present are, what the level of you is compared to them, which one of you is the guest/customer, etc. No one phrase will work in all situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the polite version of 調子はどうだい would be

> ご機嫌はいかがですか?

but is usually reserved for written correspondence. Inquiring about someone's health (e.g. "How are you?") is not really used as a formal greeting in Japanese. Unless you know someone is recovering from an illness, in which case one could ask

> お加減はいかがですか?

P.S. ご調子はいかがですか? does sound weird, not just different.